# Magento inventory management

Tags: products-management, inventory

I'm new to Magento and trying to create an online store where orders need to be assigned to retailers for fulfilment. Hence, I need Retailers to keep track of their own stock so that  the order can be routed to them depending on their stock. What can be the design option for this scenario?

Comment: Look into dropshipping modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento provides inventory management features by default, though this question is quite vague and the answers could encompass anything from designing an API for them to check or completely redesigning the system completely to be merchant specific.

You can view this link to find out how to enable inventory: [Magento - Wiki - ADMIN: System → Configuration → Inventory Tab](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/cataloginventory)

From there onwards, the SKUs you decide to manage stock on will show accurate inventory levels, and allow you to set up additional attributes like back-orderability etc.